# Can I see a plain TeX source file please?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

all the LaTeX-tutorials tell me how LaTeX is an extention simplifying the building of TeX documents. Understandably, no one uses plain TeX anymore, right?

But I seem to learn better when I grasp the link between TeX and LaTeX. Does someone have a link to example files in plain TeX? I'd like to know which commands, macros etc. are LaTeX-specific.

Comment: See now also `xcix.tex` in [What is the most bizarre thing you have seen done with TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156937).

Comment: I never use LaTeX. I've written about a million words in plainTeX and am currently typesetting a collection of notes on learning Japanese with it (using XeTeX for font-handling) with kanji and furigana which needed about three lines of TeX to implement. I've never seen a convincing argument for the complexity and inflexibility of LaTeX. Just saying.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
% Plain TeX for a 1 page document

%% The lines between the two rows of %'s are more or less compulsory.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\magnification=\magstep1
\baselineskip=12pt
\hsize=6.3truein
\vsize=8.7truein
\font\footsc=cmcsc10 at 8truept
\font\footbf=cmbx10 at 8truept
\font\footrm=cmr10 at 10truept
\footline={\footsc the electronic journal of combinatorics
   {\footbf 16} (2009), \#R00\hfil\footrm\folio}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% The further structure of the front page need not be exactly as below,
%% but the header must contain the names and addresses of the authors
%% as well as the submission and acceptance dates.

\font\bigrm=cmr12 at 14pt
\centerline{\bigrm An elementary proof of the reconstruction conjecture}

\bigskip\bigskip

\centerline{D. Remifa\footnote*{Thanks to
  the editors of this wonderful journal!}}
\smallskip
\centerline{Department of Inconsequential Studies}
\centerline{Solatido College, North Kentucky, USA}
\centerline{\tt remifa@dis.solatido.edu}

\bigskip

\centerline{\footrm 
Submitted: Jan 1, 2009; Accepted: Jan 2, 2009; Published: Jan 3, 2009}
\centerline{\footrm Mathematics Subject Classifications: 05C88, 05C89}

\bigskip\bigskip

\centerline{\bf Abstract}
\smallskip
{\narrower\noindent
The reconstruction conjecture states that the multiset of unlabeled
vertex-deleted subgraphs of a graph determines the graph, provided it
has at least 3 vertices.  A version of the problem was first stated
by Stanis\l aw Ulam.  In this paper, we show that the conjecture can
be proved by elementary methods.  It is only necessary to integrate
the Lenkle potential of the Broglington manifold over the quantum
supervacillatory measure in order to reduce the set of possible
counterexamples to a small number (less than a trillion).  A simple
computer program that implements Pipletti's classification theorem
for torsion-free Aramaic groups with simplectic socles can then
finish the remaining cases.\par}

\bigskip

\beginsection 1. Introduction.

This is the start of the introduction.

\bye
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't even have a \documentclass and it says \bye at the end. Tee hee hee. Thanks :)

Comment: @Alexx: Well, not that simple! LaTeX introduces a lot of macros into TeX. Obviously, you can't use them in plain TeX.

Answer (score 19):

Since TH took the chance to post xii.tex, I take the chance and post my further condensed version (needs almost 14% less key strokes for the same output `:-)`). This exercise was indeed my first plunge into the inner workings of TeX.

```
\let~\catcode~`76~`A13~`F1~`j00~`P2jdefA71F~`7113jdefPA;;FP
AYYFvePAJJ7172F72e71PAEE71"72F72i71PAGG71Fo71dPAWW71;FPADDF
PA**7172F727171PAKK7172F72r71PAqq71.F71Kse71PAIIFoPAXXFKdiP
AQQFjbigskipDOPAzzFhPAHHFDPATT7172F72a71PAZZFTDDPAUU71,72MF
jpar71ing;jifx:72jelseU72MjfiPABB71W72;73,74:Fjif.74.jelseB
74:jfiQn tJ;z7172tz; TydDIfDCEzs;tTsm;DmWa;y "KKJtDulIY TYg
tI J;mU7173,74:MPB tJlwWf;Wq;Yq K*dmu.,eJYlnW;q Ep"p.,JntW;
lKsGZlTpe,En"nW;eDTJlsE "dTndc,Egz"eW;t Emd"TsZElk"m,JYsnW;
sTnwWo;sZs*mE"w,Ex"sW; Jg*JZsTyl,E"fWf;Y gGlEDng"KsW,fIurW;
TlcEngD"lbXsW,tzWXW;K*J JfKncz JnzsW,WJcsGnW;tWace;wI tKtuJ
DldIYsW,WKsE"ftW;aHAHHFndZPKpTEt"KdJEgn"DZpJTKDtK*J.W,:jbye
```

Comment: it should be said that this isn't really typical of plain tex docs :-}

Answer (score 17):

There are many examples of plain TeX source files. For example all my books
and articles are written in plain TeX:

- [TeXbook naruby / TeXbook inside out](http://petr.olsak.net/tbn.html)
- [Lineární algebra](http://petr.olsak.net/linal.html)
- ...

There is an example of Bachelor thesis written in plain TeX (including
sources):

- [Kvadratické rovnice na slovech](http://www.olsak.net/mirek/bakalarka/)

It is not true that plain TeX doesn't give possibility to separate the
*logical markup* from *typesetting tasks*. I and my students
consistently respect this rule. You can verify this in sources of mentioned
bachelor thesis, for example.

Unfortunatelly, `texbook.tex` isn't good example because the typesetting macros
are mixed with text here. There are `\def's` inside document, `\eject`, etc.

You can create bad document (where the typesetting task is mixed with logical
markup) or good document independently off the basic used macro is plain TeX or
LaTeX. From this point of view, the accepted answer here is *bad example* of
good practice in plain TeX, because there are `\bigskip\bigskip`,
`\centerline` `\indent` etc. inside author's part of the document.

Finally, I disagree, that the example by David Carlisle is the typical
example of plain TeX. This is only an example of TeX capabilities. The plain
TeX has no common with it. You can create the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\bye{\end{document}}
\let~\catcode~`76~`A13~`F1~`j00~`P2jdefA71F~`7113jdefPALLF
PA''FwPA;;FPAZZFLaLPA//71F71iPAHHFLPAzzFenPASSFthP;A$$FevP
A@@FfPARR717273F737271P;ADDFRgniPAWW71FPATTFvePA**FstRsamP
AGGFRruoPAqq71.72.F717271PAYY7172F727171PA??Fi*LmPA&&71jfi
Fjfi71PAVVFjbigskipRPWGAUU71727374 75,76Fjpar71727375Djifx
:76jelse&U76jfiPLAKK7172F71l7271PAXX71FVLnOSeL71SLRyadR@oL
RrhC?yLRurtKFeLPFovPgaTLtReRomL;PABB71 72,73:Fjif.73.jelse
B73:jfiXF71PU71 72,73:PWs;AMM71F71diPAJJFRdriPAQQFRsreLPAI
I71Fo71dPA!!FRgiePBt'el@ lTLqdrYmu.Q.,Ke;vz vzLqpip.Q.,tz;
;Lql.IrsZ.eap,qn.i. i.eLlMaesLdRcna,;!;h htLqm.MRasZ.ilk,%
s$;z zLqs'.ansZ.Ymi,/sx ;LYegseZRyal,@i;@ TLRlogdLrDsW,@;G
LcYlaDLbJsW,SWXJW ree @rzchLhzsW,;WERcesInW qt.'oL.Rtrul;e
doTsW,Wk;Rri@stW aHAHHFndZPpqar.tridgeLinZpe.LtYer.W,:jbye
```

and process it by LaTeX. Will you claim that this is typical LaTeX document?

**Edit** I'd show the same example as in the accepted answer here (by Sadeq) but with the separated parts: macros and the author's text. The author can be somebody else than the programmer of the macros.

The plain TeX file created by the author of the text would be:

```
\input macros

\title      {An elementary proof of the reconstruction conjecture}
\author     {D. Remifa\footnote*{Thanks to the editors of this wonderful journal!}}
\department {Department of Inconsequential Studies}   
\address    {Solatido College, North Kentucky, USA}
\email      {remifa@dis.solatido.edu}
\edinfo     {Submitted: Jan 1, 2009; Accepted: Jan 2, 2009; Published: Jan 3, 2009\nl
             Mathematics Subject Classifications: 05C88, 05C89}
\printdata

\abstract
The reconstruction conjecture states that the multiset of unlabeled
vertex-deleted subgraphs of a graph determines the graph, provided it
has at least 3 vertices.  A version of the problem was first stated
by Stanis\l aw Ulam.  In this paper, we show that the conjecture can
be proved by elementary methods.  It is only necessary to integrate
the Lenkle potential of the Broglington manifold over the quantum
supervacillatory measure in order to reduce the set of possible
counterexamples to a small number (less than a trillion).  A simple 
computer program that implements Pipletti's classification theorem 
for torsion-free Aramaic groups with simplectic socles can then  
finish the remaining cases.

\section Introduction.

This is the start of the introduction.

\bye
```

The `macros.tex` file declares (1) the markup and (2) the dessign of the document:

```
\magnification=\magstep1
\font\footsc=cmcsc10 at 8truept
\font\footbf=cmbx10 at 8truept
\font\footrm=cmr10 at 10truept
\footline={\footsc the electronic journal of combinatorics
   {\footbf 16} (2009), \#R00\hfil\footrm\folio}
\font\bigrm=cmr12 at 14pt

\newtoks\title   \newtoks\author \newtoks\department
\newtoks\address \newtoks\email  \newtoks\edinfo

\def\printdata{\par
   \centerline{\bigrm\the\title}\vskip2\baselineskip
   \if^\the\author^\else \centerline{\the\author}\medskip\fi
   \if^\the\department^\else \centerline{\the\department}\fi   
   \if^\the\address^\else \centerline{\the\address}\fi
   \if^\the\email^\else \centerline{\tt\the\email}\fi
   \if^\the\edinfo^\else \bigskip
      {\footrm \leftskip=0pt plus1fill \rightskip=\leftskip \the\edinfo\par}\fi
   \vskip2\baselineskip
}
\def\nl{\hfil\break}  

\def\abstract{\par\centerline{\bf Abstract}\smallskip
   \bgroup \def\par{\endgraf\bigskip\egroup}  
   \narrower \noindent
}
\newcount\secnum
\def\section#1\par{\global\advance\secnum by1 
   \csname beginsection\endcsname \the\secnum. #1\par
}
```

The output is exactly the same as in the accepted answer here.

Comment: +1 BTW I can't read anywhere that `xii.tex` were a *typical* example. @TH. calling it the *best* source is of course a bit subjective :)

Comment: OK, it isn't typical example. But it is mentioned in this thread. Will somebody claim that my example above is the best LaTeX source?

Comment: @wipet I think that was more like a *joke*. By the way, those are nice links.

Comment: @wipet my smiley was supposed to indicate that I interpreted “best” as a joke. (IMHO it's a quite obvious one, too, but I may well be mistaken...)

Comment: @cgnieder OK, joke. But the background of this joke is based on the fact, that there is a connection (in your brain) between xii.tex and plain TeX. Maybe plain TeX is so mysterious? I don't see any connection. That is the reason why I didn't understand this joke.

Comment: @wipet to me it is funny since `xii.tex` quite obviously is *not* the best plain TeX source (sorry David). Of course *nobody* writes their documents this way. Why would I claim plain TeX to be mysterious? Anyway: all I wanted to say was: good answer.

Answer (score 15):

if you really want to be boggled by a plain tex source file, go to the ur-source:
http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex

this is what it says it is -- the source of the texbook -- and it has been made available by don knuth so that people can see how he solved various problems.  it shouldn't be tex'ed without his permission.

of course, it's most meaningful when viewed together with the printed version; try to find someone who can lend you a copy.

the formatting depends on a collection of macros created specifically for the purpose; \input manmac.tex makes these available.  that file is included in the tex live distribution and it's worth taking a look at it to see how it differs from latex packages.  it's my opinion that, whatever the flavor of the input one might be using for a tex job, the first order of business is to decide on (design, if necessary) the basic user interface, and only then embark on the input of the content.  from there, they will most often develop in parallel.

Comment: I think both the TeXbook and wipet's example elsewhere in this thread are not truly Plain TeX: they use an external [manmac|macros].tex file. In fact, they define alternative markup languages, based on Plain TeX macros.

Comment: @elford -- strictly speaking, you are correct.  knuth never envisioned use of plain tex as a "final" interface for anything non-trivial.  (and i don't know anyone who would disagree with that point of view, except, perhaps, the author of `xii.tex`.)  `plain.tex` is a useful starting point for building one's own special-purpose interface.  i don't think i've come across anything in `plain.tex` that i've ever had to *un*define.

Answer (score 9):

The best plain TeX source is David Carlisle's xii.tex:

```
\let~\catcode~`76~`A13~`F1~`j00~`P2jdefA71F~`7113jdefPALLF
PA''FwPA;;FPAZZFLaLPA//71F71iPAHHFLPAzzFenPASSFthP;A$$FevP
A@@FfPARR717273F737271P;ADDFRgniPAWW71FPATTFvePA**FstRsamP
AGGFRruoPAqq71.72.F717271PAYY7172F727171PA??Fi*LmPA&&71jfi
Fjfi71PAVVFjbigskipRPWGAUU71727374 75,76Fjpar71727375Djifx
:76jelse&U76jfiPLAKK7172F71l7271PAXX71FVLnOSeL71SLRyadR@oL
RrhC?yLRurtKFeLPFovPgaTLtReRomL;PABB71 72,73:Fjif.73.jelse
B73:jfiXF71PU71 72,73:PWs;AMM71F71diPAJJFRdriPAQQFRsreLPAI
I71Fo71dPA!!FRgiePBt'el@ lTLqdrYmu.Q.,Ke;vz vzLqpip.Q.,tz;
;Lql.IrsZ.eap,qn.i. i.eLlMaesLdRcna,;!;h htLqm.MRasZ.ilk,%
s$;z zLqs'.ansZ.Ymi,/sx ;LYegseZRyal,@i;@ TLRlogdLrDsW,@;G
LcYlaDLbJsW,SWXJW ree @rzchLhzsW,;WERcesInW qt.'oL.Rtrul;e
doTsW,Wk;Rri@stW aHAHHFndZPpqar.tridgeLinZpe.LtYer.W,:jbye
```

Comment: So you found your chance to [post xii.tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7869/1235). How do you like my version? `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: Heh. I wondered if anyone would remember that comment. I like your version. One of these days, I'll actually go to the trouble of figuring out more than the first three lines.

Answer (score 7):

To counter your suggestion that nobody uses Plain TeX any more, I recently switched from LaTeX to Plain TeX. It allows much more control over what goes onto the page, whereas LaTeX is a little presumptuous about what the user wants.

In particular, I have a program which stores an internal model which I want to visualise using TeX. LaTeX doesn't quite line up with that model. My program simply serialises the model into a sequence of TeX macro calls, and I \def those macros in another .tex file to appear exactly how I want them.

So here is a generated plain-tex file:

```
% Generated code
\input model.tex

\modeltitlepage{This is a sweet document dooD}{1 August 2014}

\modelsection{Part A: The start}

Once upon a time there was a document.  It was nice.

\modelitem{0}{1}{
Eggs and ham
\modelitem{1}{1.1}{
Eggs
}
\modelitem{1}{1.2}{
Ham
}
}

\modelsection{Part B: The end}

\modeltable{2}{
\modelrow{
\modelcell{the}
\modelcell{end}
}
}

\bye
```

LaTeX is only simpler in the circumstances it is designed for.

Comment: latex itself wasn't designed for most of the uses it now serves; it was designed to provide a basis on which software, to produce specific documents, will run — not (in fact) much different from knuth’s aim in designing plain tex.  these arguments about which is “best” are members of that subclass of all arguments which generate more heat than light; they're also off-topic for a question about plain tex code samples.  (and all of the argument has ignored context, which is another fine contender.)

Comment: I am a little confused about your comment. I gave an answer to the question "Can I see a plain TeX source file please?". I also gave an answer to the question "Understandably, no one uses plain TeX anymore, right?". The original question didn't mention ConTeXt at all.
I am pretty new on t.se so I'd appreciate feedback on what I could have done better in my answer!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a reference card for (plain) TeX by J.H. Silverman: http://refcards.com/docs/silvermanj/tex/tex-refcard-a4.pdf

I find it invaluable.

Comment: I think that card looks really useful, but it isn't really what the questioner asked for: an _example_ of a TeX document...

Comment: @Seamus: OP concluded with his ultimate goal: "I'd like to know which commands, macros etc. are LaTeX-specific." It is far easier to go the other way around: "Which commands are TeX-specific", don't you think?

Comment: The link is broken; but there is a copy [on the Wayback Machine here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121016172812/http://refcards.com/docs/silvermanj/tex/tex-refcard-a4.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

[CTAN contains a "package" that's precisely "samples of plain TeX coding"](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/samples).
Some of its (very old) files are like LaTeX packages, defining macros but not typesetting any actual content.
But the files `politic.tex` and `immig.tex` are the sources for two academic articles, so probably qualify as examples of plain TeX "real world" documents.

For example, `politic.tex` starts like this:

```
\magnification=1200
\count0=0
\newcount\enf\enf=0
\newcount\test
\newcount\fotnum\fotnum=0
\newcount\ftnm\ftnm=0
\def\en#1{\advance\fotnum by1{${}^{\number\fotnum}$}{#1}\par}
\def\nt{\advance\ftnm by1${}^{\number\ftnm}$~}
\def\pnt{\advance\ftnm by1${}^{\number\ftnm}$~~}
\def\quote#1{{\par\vskip12pt\narrower\narrower\baselineskip=12pt
\noindent#1\par}}
\def\cb#1{\centerline{\bf#1}}
\nopagenumbers
\baselineskip=24pt
\raggedbottom
\headline{\test=\count0\advance\test by\enf
\ifnum\test>1\rm Bowers, Christopher David\hfil Page \folio
\else\hfil\fi}
\footline{\ifnum\count0=1\hss\rm\folio\hss\fi}
{\baselineskip=12pt
\strut
\vfill
\cb{An Analysis of}
\cb{Some Determinants of Voter Turnout}
\vfill
\cb{Prepared for}
\cb{Dr. James L. Franke}
\cb{Professor of Political Science}
\cb{Texas A\&M University}
\cb{College Station, Texas}
\vfill
\cb{Submitted by}
\cb{Chris Bowers}
\cb{Route 5~~Box 1338}
\cb{College Station, Texas~~77840}
\vfill
\cb{March 5, 1984}
\vfill\eject}
\strut\vskip1.1truein
During the past twenty years, one of the most important trends in
American politics has been the reduction in the percentage of the electorate
that votes.\pnt  In view of this change, this paper will focus upon the
modern determinants of turnout---in other words, the factors that influence
whether or not citizens vote.
```