# How do you say Happy New Year with LaTeX?

Tags: programming, javascript

Title says it all. How do you wish "Happy New Year" to a TeXie? Compile the code below with pdfLaTeX, view it with "PDF Reader" or "Adobe Acrobat Pro" and press the "Happy New Year" button on the second page. Please suggest ways to internationalize the "Happy New Year" string by adding translations in the comments in your language.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled =.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{soul}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{5.2075in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{4.90in}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{phv}
\usepackage[pdftex,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{A Sample Calculation}\chead{}
\rhead{Area of Circle}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{}\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfpagelayout=SinglePage,
pdftitle={Wishing you a happy year},pdfsubject={Invest your new year improving your TeX skills}%
]{hyperref}

\definecolor{background}{rgb}{0.99,0.98,0.90}
\pagecolor{background}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}


\begin{insDLJS}[test]{test}{JavaScript}

function doCalculation()
{
var radius=0.0 + this.getField("radius").value;
 this.getField("diameter").value=radius*2;
 this.getField("areacircle").value=  Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
}

function HappyNewYear()
{
 app.alert("Happy New Year!",3);
}


\end{insDLJS}

%% This must be here
%\OpenAction{/S/JavaScript/JS(docOpen();)}

%% Short hand commands
\newcommand{\textforlabel}[2]{%
\TextField[name={#1}, value={#2}, width=9em,align=2,%
    bordercolor={0.990 .980 .85},%
 readonly=true]{}%
}


%% Define the heading
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\so{#1}}
\def\spacer#1{\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}\\*[#1]}

\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt
\vphantom{-Z}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\textbf{\Huge Have a Happy New Year\\ with JavaScript\\*[4pt] and LateX!}

\end{center}
\vfill
\newpage

\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{|rl|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}\\*[-0.8em]\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{%
\heading{Area of Circle}}\\

%% 
%%% Input field radius

&\\*[-0.8em]\textforlabel{l01}{Radius:}&\TextField[name=radius,width=10em, bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94}]{}%
~m\\



&\\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\heading{Calculate}}\\
\spacer{-0.8em}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{
%% Push button is defined here
\PushButton[name=start,onclick={doCalculation();},bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94}%
]{Calculate} 

%% Push button is defined here
\PushButton[name=hello,%
onclick={HappyNewYear();}, bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94}%
]{Happy New Year!} 
}\\

\spacer{-0.8em}
\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\heading{Results}}\\

%% RESULTS
%% Diameter
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}\\*[-0.8em]\textforlabel{name=l04, bordercolor={0.650 0.790 0.94}}{%
Diameter :}&\TextField[name=diameter,width=10em,bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94},%
readonly=true]{}~m\\
\spacer{-0.8em}

\textforlabel{name=l05, bordercolor={0.650 0.790 0.94}}{Area:} & \TextField[name=areacircle,width=10em,%
bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94},readonly=true]{}~m$^2$\\*[-0.8em]
\spacer{1em}
\spacer{1em}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\bigskip

\parindent0.5em
As proved by Archimedes, the area enclosed by a circle is $\pi$ multiplied by the radius squared \(\pi r^2\). Apollonius of Perga showed that a circle may also be defined as the set of points in a plane having a constant ratio (other than 1) of distances to two fixed foci, A and B.

Early science, particularly geometry and astrology and astronomy, was connected to the divine for most medieval scholars, and many believed that there was something intrinsically \textit{divine} or \textit{perfect} that could be found in circles. Some people still believe that the earth is still flat and is circular.


Some highlights in the history of the circle are:
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1700 BC -- The Rhind papyrus gives a method to find the area of a circular field. The result corresponds to \(\frac{256}{81}\) (3.16049\dots) as an approximate value of $\pi$.
\item 300 BC -- Book 3 of Euclid's Elements deals with the properties of circles.
In Plato's Seventh Letter there is a detailed definition and explanation of the circle. Plato explains the perfect circle, and how it is different from any drawing, words, definition or explanation.
\item 1880 -- Lindemann proves that $\pi$ is transcendental, effectively settling the millennia-old problem of squaring the circle
\item 1978 -- Donald Knuth develops \TeX\ in order to enable future generations to typeset Mathematics in a beautiful way, including all the equations that one can associate with circles.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is interesting! All javascript libraries can work with LaTeX ?

Comment: @xport Not all. You cannot use jQuery or any of the libraries that handle the XHTML document model. Adobe has its own model, but Adobe's JS is based on ECMA so you can pretty much use any other routines you may have. Don't forget to add Happy New Year in your `\language`!

Comment: @Yiannis, if  you have time, please show me how animation can work in pdf using Adobe ECMA javascript.

Comment: Someone should have posted xii.tex a few days ago.

Comment: I tried to pdfLaTeX the above code but I get the error message: ! LaTeX Error: File `insdljs.sty' not found. I have the TeXLive 2010. Anyone getting this error message?

Comment: @yCalleecharan It is part of the acrotex package.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand right, then acrotex is not part of TeXLive.

Comment: @yCalleecharan, just download from CTAN.

Comment: Thanks. I did the installation i.e. LateXing acrotex.ins and put all the files in a folder under TeXLive 2010 and update the database with the TeXLive Manager but pdfLaTeX still complains: insdljs.sty not found. What is wrong?

Comment: @yCalleecharan Maybe you post a separate question someone might be able to help you with TeXLive (I use MikTeX).

Comment: @xport: JavaScript driven animation has already been packaged for you in the animate package available on CTAN.

Comment: @Alexander: OK, thanks. I will play with it later. :-)

Comment: @Alexander. Does it work on iPad's iBook?

Comment: @xport: Yes, if there exists an AdobeReader (v>=7) for iPads, but I'm afraid it doesn't. On iBooks you have MacOSX. Hence Adobe Reader should run thereon.

Comment: @Alexander: I have view your `animate.pdf` on my iPad using iBook and the animation does not appear.

Comment: @xport: I didn't know that iBook is a software on iPads. I thought you meant the hardware of the same name. Apologies for misunderstanding you.

Comment: @Alexander: No problem. :-) It is just for confirmation.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides : Ok, I will do this when I have time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AdobeReader comes in about 15 different languages. This is the number of possible translations of your new year's wishes. The language version of the Reader in which the PDF is opened can be accessed using the JavaScript object `app.language`. See:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JS_API_AcroJSPreface.87.1.html#1515775&accessible=true

It can be used to choose the matching greeting. I did this for French and German and some default language which appears to be the most widespread one (according to the number of speakers). However, it may require an additional font pack to be installed ;-) :

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4883

Just replace your definition of the function `HappyNewYear()` with the following code:

```js
function HappyNewYear()
{
  switch(app.lang){
    case "FRA":
    hny="Bonne Ann"+String.fromCharCode(233)+"e !";break;;
    case "DE":
    hny="Gl"+String.fromCharCode(252)+"ckliches Neues Jahr!";break;;
    default:
    hny=String.fromCharCode(26032,24180,24555,20048)+"!";
  }
  app.alert(hny,3);
}
```

Note that some non-ascii characters had to be replaced by their Unicode representation.

Comment: It's the first "e" in "Année" that should be accented...

Comment: @Seamus: Of course, you are right.

Comment: @Seamus: And as far as I know, French typography wants a space before the exclamation mark while German typography forbids it.

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure about the details of typography conventions, but basic spelling I can manage...

Comment: @Alexander `tts.qText("Thanks, and have a Happy New Year");`. Default made my other half very happy:)

Comment: @Yiannis: Is your question answered now? (I would like to break the 200 reputation score :)

Comment: @Alexander It is!