# acroTeX and TeXLive 2010

Tags: pdftex, installing, texlive, acrotex

this is a follow-up of the post: How do you say Happy New Year with LaTeX?

[How do you say Happy New Year with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7869/how-do-you-say-happy-new-year-with-latex)

It sounds great to be able to use LaTeX for such greetings but however I have been unsuccessful with TexLive 2010. I performed the installation of acroTeX from CTAN i.e. LateXing acrotex.ins and put all the files in a folder under TeXLive 2010 and update the database with the TeXLive Manager but pdfLaTeX still complains: insdljs.sty not found though insdljs.sty exists. What is wrong?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: There's no way to know what is wrong unless you tell us _where_ exactly `insdljs.sty` is.

Comment: @mpg : Thanks. I created a folder acrotex as in C:\texlive\2010\acrotex and the insdljs.sty is there in that folder. Maybe it is not the right location???

Comment: Nope, it's not. You should place it somewhere under `C:\texlive\2010\texmf-local\tex`, preferably in a `latex\acrotex` subdiretory. Then update the database again and it should work.

Comment: @mpg : Thanks a lot. Now it works. I have it as: C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\local\acrotex . You have provided me with the right answer. If you wish, then please turn your comments into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @mpg. Converting your comment to an answer would be useful here: the question can then move off the 'unanswered' list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mpg answered in the comments:

> You should place it [the template] somewhere under `C:\texlive\2010\texmf-local\tex`, preferably in a `latex\acrotex` subdiretory. Then update the database again and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer that "mpg" already supplied but since he hasn't converted his comment to a "proper" reply for a long time now, I am accepting your answer.