# eforms vs hyperref

Tags: hyperref, forms

I need to create fillable pdf files. In first time I need just to add combox that contains Yes/No in a column of a table. I have looked questions here and I found this :

[Creating fillable PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs)

[How do you say Happy New Year with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7869/how-do-you-say-happy-new-year-with-latex)

They suggest to use `hyperref` or `eforms` packages.

I'm interested in `eforms` package as we create amazing things.

My questions : 
Why eforms is not texlive package? Do I need Acrobat Reader (Pro?) to get my forms fully working? Is  hyperref is a good alternative to `eforms`?

Comment: I hope that someone answers the question suggested in the title (Is hyperref a good alternative to eforms?)

Answer (score 10):

The [`eforms`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eforms) package produces PDFs which use Adobe Reader-specific code (specials) to achieve its effects. As such, whilst the code can be used in a free-as-in-beer sense (the package is licensed under the LPPL and Adobe Reader is a free download), it is not usable in a free-as-in-speech manner (Adobe Reader is only available as a binary). The [TeX Live policy](https://www.tug.org/texlive/copying.html) includes a requirement that

> the material in TeX Live should not require nonfree software to be useful.

which rules out any packages which only work using closed-source products, *even when* the packages themselves have open-source licenses. This applies not only to `eforms` but also to a variety of font support bundles, *etc.* You will need to install `eforms` manually.