# What is the difference between TeX and Texinfo?

Tags: texinfo, texi2dvi

I want to know if I can compile raw TeX code with the `texi2pdf` program.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about the difference between `Plain` TeX and `texinfo`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 15):

`Texinfo` is yet another macro package which defines its own markup language, which may be processed by TeX to produce dvi (texi2dvi) or pdf (texi2pdf). You may include arbitrary (roughly, plain) TeX code inside the `@iftex` and `@end iftex` commands; but then, anything within this conditional will be ignored in conversion to other formats (html, info, etc.). `texi2[dvi|pdf]` are shell scripts that automate the processing of Texinfo files to produce documentation for printing, analogous to `makeinfo`, a program which processes the same documentation to produce online documentation in info or html formats, for instance.

`texi2pdf` may also process automatically LaTeX files, by checking the filename extension. Thus, `texi2pdf filename.tex` automatically processes `filename.tex` as a LaTeX file, with its main byproducts (bibtex and makeindex).

You may trick `texi2pdf` into processing Plain TeX files with the strategies suggested by Fran; but then you would be only forcing the `texi2pdf` script to use the `pdftex` engine with the `pdftex` format on the Plain TeX file, and the result would be the same as using the command `pdftex filename.tex`.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is not terribly clear. As I understand it, you are asking whether you can compile raw `.tex` code using `texi2pdf` ***without installing a TeX distribution***.

The answer to that question is that you cannot because `texi2pdf` just acts as a wrapper which depends on the availability of compilation commands provided by a TeX distribution.

Note that my reason for interpreting your question in this way, rather than the way everyone else is interpreting it, is that I cannot currently imagine any other motivation for it. That is, if you have a TeX distribution installed, you might just as soon use `pdftex` or `pdflatex` to compile a `.tex` file: the only reason to use the wrappers provided by `texinfo` is that you are dealing with a `.texi` file ***rather than*** a `.tex` one.

So while it is presumably possible to use `texi2pdf` to compile `.tex` files, it is hard to see why anybody would do that.

The base wrapper is `texi2dvi`. `texi2pdf` is a shorthand enabling the use of the pdfTeX engine in place of the standard TeX one.

Running `texi2dvi` on a `.texi` file is equivalent to the following 5 steps, according to the documentation:

> 1. Run 'tex' on your Texinfo file.  This generates a DVI file (with
>       undefined cross-references and no indices), and the raw index files
>       (with two letter extensions).
> 2. Run 'texindex' on the raw index files.  This creates the
>       corresponding sorted index files (with three letter extensions).
> 3. Run 'tex' again on your Texinfo file.  This regenerates the DVI
>       file, this time with indices and defined cross-references, but with
>       page numbers for the cross-references from the previous run,
>       generally incorrect.
> 4. Sort the indices again, with 'texindex'.
> 5. Run 'tex' one last time.  This time the correct page numbers are
>       written for the cross-references.

Steps 1, 3 and 5 require at least a minimal installation of TeX to be available. (If you are dealing with a `.tex` file, I assume steps 2 and 4 don't apply.)

Comment: The OP might also be looking for a way to automate the 'repeatedly run TeX and ancillary programs until the cross-references converge' process.

Comment: using `texi2pdf filename.tex` and setting `(PDF)LATEX=(pdf)tex` are documented. Indeed, using `texi2dvi|pdf` to process automatically latex, bibtex and makeindex files is supported. It is all in the info manual. So using `texi2dvi` for (La)TeX files is not violent at all; it might even be convenient.

Comment: @zwol True. There are more straightforward ways to do that, though.

Comment: @wicho I didn't suggest it was `violent`. I think it doesn't make sense to do it because there are simpler options for automation which will also deal with many features not supported by `texinfo`.

Comment: Insightful answer to a very vague question.

Comment: `violent` is indeed a strong word. Perhaps I meant `weird`. Anyway: the idea is that `texi2dvi|pdf` is able to process `LaTeX` files, with their common byproducts (`makeindex` and `bibtex`), automatically; and by tricking the script into assuming `[pdf]latex=[pdf]tex`, it may automate the processing of Plain TeX files. There are alternatives, indeed, but that does not seem to be the intention of the OP.

Comment: @wicho I'm afraid your crystal ball is much more effective than mine, in that case, as I would say it is very unclear what the OP is asking. Even if you are correct and the OP's interest is automation, there are still better options. I can't think of any reason to use `texinfo` rather than one of those other options, though no doubt somebody can dream up some circumstances in which the former would be preferable.

Comment: I fear you also mistake texi2[dvi|pdf] for Texinfo.

Comment: @wicho They are part of `texinfo`. That is, they are wrappers provided by `texinfo` which rely on the installation of a TeX distribution. If you install `texinfo`, you have these wrappers but they are useless unless you install a TeX distribution as well. If this were not the case, my suggested interpretation of the OP's post would be (almost) certainly mistaken as opposed to being one plausible reading of an extremely unclear question.

Answer (score 7):

According to `man texi2pdf` to process (e)plain TeX files, one must set the environment variable `LATEX=tex`. This is true for the DVI ouput with `texi2dvi` or `texi2pdf --dvi`, to use the `etex` engine instead of `latex`, but for a PDF output the setting really should be  `PDFLATEX=pdftex` to change the `pdflatex` engine by `pdftex`. Thus, in a Linux system with a plain TeX file  as [`test.tex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6493/11604), the procedure could be:

```
$ PDFLATEX=pdftex ; export PDFLATEX ; texi2pdf test.tex
```

Or alternatively, inform to the program that the source code is a TeXinfo file, in spite of the `.tex` extension:

```
$ texi2pdf --language=texinfo test.tex
```

Or more tricky, change the extension. Not necessarily must be that of the texinfo files (`.texi`) since names without `.tex`, not being recognized as LaTeX files, will be treated as texinfo files, in spite of any other suffix (or even if there are not any suffix). So you can name it, for instance, `test.foo`.

In Linux, one can use hard links to maintain several names for the same file, so you can maintain the original file name  `test.tex` but use `test.foo` to be compiled with `texi2pdf`:

```
$ ln test.tex test.foo
$ texi2pdf  test.foo
```

As explained in another answer, deceiving the program in this way work since TeXinfo files are based in plain TeX, and thus using the same engines, but you run the risk of deceiving yourself with a misleading or non standard suffix.

Comment: @erreka Yes, as I said, setting the environment variable to `tex`  failed, i.e., still run `pdflatex`, not `pdftex`, but the plain TeX passed as a texinfo file run `pdftex`, so really this is not needed at all, as far I can see.

Comment: @erreka Is the typical cryptic advice of man page, that is the same for two programs, so it take some time to figure what really mean. `:(` In a pure Linux also work set `PDFLATEX` instead of `LATEX`.

Comment: @wicho   I really mean: Use the extension [whatever you like, except `.tex`]. I edited the answer to clarify.  The `.info` was simply the first non `.tex` and  `.texi` suffix  that came to  my mind. It is hard today find not "reserved" extensions.